# Terraform GCP Data catalog Policy Tag

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform, google-data-catalog

Is it is possible to create Policy Tag in Data Catalog for Bigquery Column level security using Terraform . I'm not seeing any resource for policy tag in terraform documentation.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/data_catalog_entry.html

Comment: Perhaps you can look into using "google_data_catalog_tag" as it will allow you to attach custom metadata to Data Catalog resources. Tags conform to the specifications within their tag template. https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/data_catalog_tag.html

Comment: this will create normal tag which is different from policy tag..
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-level-security

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/data_catalog_tag.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managing Policy Tags using Terraform is not yet supported as of today (2020-09-24), but it's being worked on: see https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/6075.

Answer (score 1):

As of today (2021-06-15), Policy Tags are supported with the `terraform-provider-google-beta` provider.

See documentation for [google_data_catalog_policy_tag](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/data_catalog_policy_tag) resource.

Comment: Policy Tags is supported now but I think what's missing in terraform is how to set a BigQuery column with a given policy tag https://github.com/hashicorp/Terraform-provider-google/issues/6075#issuecomment-664996465, which is still unclear to me...

Comment: Is there any update on this one? How to link Policy tag with a BQ Table column?